# RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin + iOS64 = Error

Tags: delphi, device

Delphi Berlin 10.1 + iOS64 = Error

App closes without any message, just leave a message in the log iOS:
"Received memory warning."

The Code only does this:

```
var
   frm: TMyForm;
begin
   frm: = TMyForm.Create (nil);
   frm.ShowModal;
   frm.Free;
end;
```

As you click the button about 8 times it is when it gives the error.

Anyone know how to solve this problem ???

Answer (score 4):

From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ShowModal):

> **Caution:** Modal dialog boxes are not supported in Android apps. Instead of calling **ShowModal**, you should call [Show](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Show), and have the form return and call your event.
>   We recommend do not use modal dialog boxes on either of the mobile platforms (iOS and Android) because unexpected behavior can result. Avoiding usage of modal dialog boxes eliminates potential problems in debugging and supporting your mobile apps.

The correct way in firemonkey to show a [modal](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Modal_Dialog_Boxes) dialog is:

```
procedure MyCurrentForm.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TMyModalForm;
begin
  // Create an instance of a form.
  dlg := TMyModalForm.Create(nil);

  // Configure the form. For example, give it a display name.
  dlg.Caption := 'My Modal Dialog Box';

  // Show your dialog box and provide an anonymous method that handles the closing of your dialog box.
  dlg.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      // Do something.
    end
  );
end;
```

Don't forget to set `Action := caFree;` in the `OnClose` event of the modal dialog.

> You cannot free the memory allocated for your modal dialog box form within the method than handles the closing of your modal dialog box form. To free your modal dialog box form, you must handle its OnClose event as follows:
>
> ```
>    procedure TMyModalForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
>    begin
>      Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
>    end;
> ```

Comment: OP is referring to iOS - I don't believe the same applies, does it?

Comment: @JerryDodge, The recommendation not to use modal forms is for all mobile platforms. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I missed over the part `(iOS and Android)`.

Comment: @LURD Thank you very much! You have all the reason on ShowModal.